# Can't read request headers on deploy server

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-rest-framework, linode

I'm working in a django project and I'm building an Api using Django Rest Framework for let users get some data on their mobile devices. I'm sending some extra paramenters in the headers dictionary for each request, not only the auth token.
I'm testing locally using the IOS simulator of xocde for make the requests . Ok, this is an example of my API view:

```
class GetChildMainInfoView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (
        TokenAuthentication,
    )
    permission_classes = (
        IsAuthenticated,
    )

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        api_key = request.META.get('HTTP_API_ID')
        child_id = request.META.get('HTTP_CHILD_ID')

        if not api_key == settings.API_KEY:
            raise Http404

        child = get_object_or_404(
            UserProfile,
            id=child_id,
        )

        if child.avatar:
            avatar = child.avatar.url
        else:
            avatar = None

        child_info = {
            'name': unicode(child),
            'picture': avatar,
        }

        return Response(child_info)
```

When I make a get request testing on my local server, all runs perfectly. But when a try It on my production server, there is some problem reading the API_ID and the CHILD_ID headers, The value is None. On my local server the response is the child_info dict but in production the response is the not found bug (Raise the buf of the if not api_key == settings.API_KEY). 
 If I remove those from my view logic and return some string like  return Response('response'), I have the response correctly in my production server, and therefore I'm sure that there is some problem reading extra headers in production server. All runs perfectly on my localhost, but in my production server there is some trouble getting only extra headers because the Authorization token runs perfectly locally and on production server, but the API_ID and the CHILD_ID headers can't be readed. My production server is an ubuntu machine on linode, the project was deployed using uwsgi and nginx and the API is Django rest framework... I really don't know what could be, maybe some DRF settings or some deploy server permission?... Than you so much for helps.

maybe can help, this is my iptables server config file.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Reset iptables rules
iptables -F

iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Web
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

# Allow all traffic from localhost
iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -p tcp -j ACCEPT

# SSH
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Drop all others
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's that, but the `request` object that you get is not the Django's `django.http.HttpRequest`, but the `rest_framework.request.Request`. You should likely use the original Django's request object `request._request`.

Thus:

```
api_key = request._request.META.get('HTTP_API_ID')
child_id = request._request.META.get('HTTP_CHILD_ID')
```

Comment: DRF's `Request` will proxy the `META` attribute to the Django `HttpRequest`, so this wouldn't be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally I found the bug... was a nginx config, a trouble with underscores in headers... http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html